# GNU Cim (Simula preprocessor): How to use INNER in a PROCEDURE declared VIRTUAL?

Tags: oop, virtual-functions

Simula (back then, *Simula 67*) introduced *virtual* procedures (amongst a lot of other things).
In contrast to practice in several later languages, a derived class would not completely "override" an ancestor's definition, but be allowed to contribute where the definition says `inner`. I think something like

```
CLASS Object; 
    VIRTUAL:
%nocomment PROCEDURE toString IS 
        TEXT PROCEDURE toString
%nocomment ;
            ;
BEGIN
    TEXT PROCEDURE toString;
    BEGIN
        TEXT t;
        t :- blanks(144);
        t.Putchar(' ');
        inner;
        toString :- Copy(t.Sub(0, t.Pos));
    END;
END;

Object CLASS Int(val); INTEGER val; BEGIN
    TEXT PROCEDURE toString; t.Putint(val);
END;

REF(Object) o; o:- NEW Int(42);
OutText(o.toString); OutImage;
```

should work with Cim, too ((as of 3.37,) Cim requires "the `%nocomment` decoration" for a declaration of a PROCEDURE as VIRTUAL to be compatible with standard conforming compilers)
- I get

> "xyz.sim", line 13: INNER is not on outermost block level in this Class.

While the `inner` conceivably isn't "on outermost block level", I want to use it in a virtual procedure:
How does this work with [Cim](https://www.gnu.org/software//gawk/cim.wait/cim.html#SEC1)?

Comment: I tried to do some research and help with this, but I'm not experienced enough with the subject matter to really provide much insight.  I did find [this](http://staff.um.edu.mt/jskl1/talk.html) tutorial which brushes on the topic of utilizing inner in simula 67 (and specifically seems to be utilizing it in a similar manner under the "prefixing blocks" bold text area).  I don't know if this is helpful or not, but it's there if it is.  Good luck!

Comment: I am sorry for contacting you this way (my comment isnt related to your input here). I came across a question you voted on in "triage" where you made the wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage carefully, to avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. I hope you see this as a chance to improve your voting. I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21076255. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me. If you give me a quick reply, I will immediately this comment here.

Answer (score 0):

[`INNER` seems](http://simula67.at.ifi.uio.no/Standard-86/chap_5.htm) to split *class bodies* ("constructors"), only, into *initial-operations* executed *before* the class body of any prefixed (derived) class and *final-operations* to be executed thereafter.

Comment: It would seem I misremembered Simula's `INNER` - not from three decades of not using Simula "in anger", but from about twelve years when I first tried to take Java seriously.